# Define BigQuery table location in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-workspace, bq

I am trying to read data form BigQuery table in Google Apps Script. Target table is located in EU region, but US is requested by default from script.

Code

```
  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT * FROM `table-name`'
  };
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```

Error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Not found: Dataset <dataset-name.table-name> was not found in location US

Answer (score 0):

Quotes `` was a problem, table name should be without without quotes :

```
 var projectId = "project_id"
 var request = {    
        query: 'SELECT * FROM data_set.table ',
      };
 var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query is expected to be automatically routed to where the data is, if you have the right dataset to qualify the table name, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `myDatasetInEu.table-name`
```

Comment: This form with `` does not work. `` was the reason of the error.

Comment: I doubt this is the root cause. If you truly have a dash in your table name, you have to quote your table name with backticks. I believe you overly simplified the query in your original question.